# Link to specific line within a table HTML / Vuetify.js

Tags: html, vue-component, anchor, vuetify.js

I am using a v-simple-table in Vuetify to display the contents of a log one line per row. I need to be able to send someone a link that will take them to a specific line within the table. I'm trying to accomplish this by using the id for each element as a hash anchor but the link just reloads the page.

```
<v-simple-table height="500px" dense>
<template v-slot:default>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(line, index) in logFile" :key="index">
      <td class="accent--text" v-show="showLineNumbers">
        <a :id="index" :href="'#/logs/view/204#'+index">{{ index }}</a>
      </td>
      <td>{{ line }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </template>
</v-simple-table>
```

This table is within a v-card within a v-container on the page. When I hover over the number for line 100 of the log for example the link previews as "{mydomain}/logs/view/204#100" and inspect element shows it has an id of 100 but going to the link in the browser just loads the page at the top.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the browser can't send the user to a portion of the page that doesn't exist, so it just stays at the top.

Now you might be thinking...

> But it's clearly there, I checked it, I see it.

However, the index you reference needs to be there at the time of opening the page, and since the content gets generated **after** the page is loaded, this functionality will not work.

If you want it to work, you're going to have to implement the scrolling yourself to happen after the table is rendered.

One way to do it is to get the index from the url.
`window.location.hash` will give you the hashbang, and then you can use a library like `vue-scrollto` to do the scroll.

Comment: That makes sense now! Thank-you - I'll have a play around with those suggestions and update my question with the ultimate solution I find.